# Installation Issue at Restart

Tags: usb-drive

Ubuntu says to restart after installation, but not to remove USB drive. So when I restarted, it went directly to the start of the installation menu, asking if I wanted to install Ubuntu. Do I need to remove the flash drive and then restart? If so does it go directly into Ubuntu or do I need to direct it via f12?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to remove your installation medium, or else it will boot into it again and try to reinstall. In most cases, it will come up with a prompt at the loading screen telling you the following short message:

```
Please remove the installation media, and press ENTER:
```

However, I have also been unlucky, particularly on VM installs with virtualbox, where it has replicated this scenario if the installation .iso was not automatically ejected from the machine.

**Footnote:** As far as I am aware, this is the same across most Linux distributions, and a very good habit to get in to in order to avoid errors.

Comment: So it is installed and will go into automatically. or do I have to use F12? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the medium for sure or else OS installation gets booted again from the flash drive, or change the boot priority to something else (like HDD) instead of USB